# Magento - Add Custom Mass Action PDF

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

**Quick Question (Keep this in mind when reading):**

Why is this error being produced (*in explanation*) and how can I edit the `pdfRmaAction()` to work correctly (Mass Action Printing)???

**Working in Magento `v.1.10.1.0` which is the same as `v.1.5.1.0`

**Long-winded explanation:**

I've downloaded this extension (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-order-printing-extension.html) to add a button to **each** order so that when you go into the order, you have an extra button to print an RMA (Customized from this extensions Model pdf - turned into a custom RMA form based on invoice)

It works great. However, I want to add Mass Action printing to it so that you can check a few orders and choose **Print RMA** from the dropdown and print the forms for those orders.

In the extensions `config.xml` file (app/code/local/Nastnet/OrderPrint/etc/), inside the `<config>` tags is this:

```
<modules>
    <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
        <version>0.1.3</version>
    </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid> <!-- ADDED THIS FOR MASS ACTION PRINTING -->
                <sales_order_view>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Block_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    <rewrite>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint_OrderController>
            <from><![CDATA[#/\w+/sales_order/print/#]]></from>
            <to>/orderprint/order/print/</to>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint_OrderController>
    </rewrite>
    <models>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
            <class>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model</class>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
    </models>
    <pdf>
        <order>
            <default>Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_items_order_default</default>
            <grouped>Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_items_order_grouped</grouped>
        </order>
    </pdf>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
             <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Nastnet_OrderPrint</module>
                <!-- This is used when "catching" the rewrite above -->
                <frontName>orderprint</frontName>
            </args>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

In (app/code/local/Nastnet/OrderPrint/Block/Sales/Order/) in `Grid.php` is this:

```
class Nastnet_OrderPrint_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();

        // Append new mass action option
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('rmaprint',
        array('label' => $this->__('Print RMA'),
              'url'   => $this->getUrl('orderprint/order/pdfRma')));
    }
}
```

This leads to the desired result of inserting "**Print RMA**" into the dropdown menu on the Sales > Orders grid view screen.

In the `OrderController.php` file (app/code/local/Nastnet/OrderPrint/controllers/) I've added this [copied and edited from the `pdfinvoicesAction()` in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php:

```
public function pdfRmaAction(){
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids');
    //print_r($orderIds);
    $flag = false;
    if (!empty($orderIds)) {
        foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
            $invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
                ->setOrderFilter($orderId)
                ->load();
                //print get_class($invoices);
                //print_r($invoices->getSize());
            if ($invoices->getSize() > 0) {
                $flag = true;
                if (!isset($pdf)){
                    $pdf = Mage::getModel('Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_order')->getPdf(array($order));
                } else {
                    $pages = Mage::getModel('Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_order')->getPdf(array($order));
                    $pdf->pages = array_merge ($pdf->pages, $pages->pages);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($flag) {
            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                'rma'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf', $pdf->render(),
                'application/pdf'
            );
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('There are no printable documents related to selected orders.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

This leads to an error in the actual pdf...

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStore() on a non-object in /chroot/home/artizara/dev.artizara.com/html/app/code/local/Nastnet/OrderPrint/Model/Order/Pdf/Order.php on line 60
```

However, if you go into the order and press the **Print RMA** button (instead of trying to Mass Action print it) then it works ***Just Fine!***

*My long winded explanation leads to this:* **Why is this error being produced and how can I edit the `pdfRmaAction()` to work correctly (Mass Action Printing)???**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you use an `$order` variable which is not set as a parameter for the function `getPdf`. You should be fine with this function:

```
public function pdfRmaAction() {
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids');
    $flag = false;
    if (!empty($orderIds)) {
        foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            $flag = true;
            $order->setOrder($order);
            if (!isset($pdf)) {
                $pdf = Mage::getModel('Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_order')->getPdf(array($order));
            } else {
                $pages = Mage::getModel('Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_order')->getPdf(array($order));
                $pdf->pages = array_merge($pdf->pages, $pages->pages);
            }
        }
        if ($flag) {
            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                'rma'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.pdf', $pdf->render(),
                'application/pdf'
            );
        } else {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('There are no printable documents related to selected orders.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```