# Magento - Add Mass Actions for Print PDF Invoice

Tags: magento, invoice

I have question, how can I add a mass action to print invoice in PDF. I need two different PDF invoice (one is default "Print Invoice"), so I want to add additional action "Print invoice 2". How can I do that to start printing "Print invoice 2"?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981315/magento-add-custom-mass-action-pdf

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to add the mass actions to the invoices grid (Sales > Invoices in the admin), you will need to do the following:

Rewrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid` class and replace it with your own.  Your new class should be in it's own extension and inherit from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid`.  If you're not sure how to rewrite a block, [this blog post should help](http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/) you out.  **Note:** You could just copy the grid block to `app/code/local/` but that makes upgrading Magento difficult.  A better approach is a rewrite and override the minimum possible amount of functionality.

Your class should provide it's own `_prepareMassaction` function which then adds the new action.  The following code (while completely untested) should do it:

```
class MyNamspace_Extension_Block_Adminhtml_Invoice_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid {
    protected function _prepareMassaction() {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order2', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('myextension')->__('PDF Invoices2'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('myroute/mycontroller/myaction'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The "url" param on the `addItem()` call should point to your own controller where you can implement your own logic for generation of PDFs.  The standard mass action PDF generator can be found in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php` at line 129 if you'd like some inspiration.

Comment: I need two mass actions in the invoices grid (Sales > Invoices. One is as default "Print Invoices" and this is ok. So I need second one  "Print Invoices 2".
I already done modify files in app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf for "Print Invoices" (this is ok) and app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdfn for "Print Invoices 2"

I have problem, because I don't know, how and what I must to do, that "Print Invoices 2" will work with files in local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdfn

Before I start modify Invoice I copy local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf to local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdfn